# Getting an error Either set MainPage or Createwindow when app launches in MAUI

Tags: ios, maui

[image]When I'm trying to deploy the app on a iOS device, I'm getting an exception in Program.cs in iOS as "Either set MainPage or CreateWindow" when the app launches, I tried overriding the CreateWindow method as a fix suggested by a few threads, but I have some dependencies due to which I can not use that, any inputs would be really helpful

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShellView();
            ResourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ResourceDictionary>();
            foreach (var dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                string key = dictionary.Source.OriginalString.Split(';').FirstOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault().Split('.').FirstOrDefault(); // Alternatively If you are good in Regex you can use that as well
                ResourceDictionary.Add(key, dictionary);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        MainPage = new AppShellView();
        return base.CreateWindow(activationState);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, ResourceDictionary> ResourceDictionary;
}
```

This is my App.xaml.cs

Comment: You need to show code...

Comment: Can you provide some code of App Class? By the way can you say how you tried overriding the CreateWindow method？You can try to look at the official lifecycle documentation: [App lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: If you don't use dependencies, can you run normally, with more detailed error logs?

Comment: you mean without overriding the createwindow, i did it gives me an exception, i've added the image of the exception @DongzhiWang-MSFT

Comment: I don't get this in simulator, but just in device

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT any inputs?

Comment: You said that it only appears in the device, and it can run normally in the simulator, right? Did you try to create an otherwise normal project that works in the device? Do you use local database in your project?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Turns out declaring double in styles as a font size is returning an exception

Comment: What did you try to cause this error? Did you try to create an otherwise normal project that works in the device?

Comment: You try to comment this line of code in App class: `MainPage = new AppShellView();`

Comment: creating a normal project also caused this error, using a Double as a font size in styles was resulting in an exception @DongzhiWang-MSFT

Comment: That means you can't create a new Maui project build to run right now? Can you tell me the version number of VS you are using?